# how to show same result as `ps aux` with Unix options?

Tags: linux, ps

I always using `ps aux` (the BSD style options) and suddenly want to know if there is a simple way to show the same result with UNIX style options because I use other command with a dash (-). I can do it like this:

```
ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tname,stat,start_time,time,cmd,
```

but I still want to know if there is a simple way to do this.
I read the manual and tried ps -e, ps -ef, ps -eF, ps -ely... all of these options did not show the process STAT. , I really want to know is there anyone using ps with unified UNIX style options to do their daily work?

Comment: look for the format options in `man ps`

Comment: I can do it like this; ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tname,stat,start_time,time,cmd, I still want to know if there is a simple way to do this

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this. I guess there is no option to get the same output as `ps aux`. Try `ps -efl` if the output suits your needs. The question is a bit academic. If your system supports `ps aux`, simply use this. If you have a system that doesn't support the BSD options, the output format is not exactly specified and the available options may vary. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ps.html

Comment: thanks @Bodo for your suggestion, done.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to create alias for your command with required options.
For example, it will have name `psunix`.
Execute in shell:

```
alias psunix='ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,tname,stat,start_time,time,cmd'
```

Check the new added alias:

```
alias
```

Further just use command:

```
psunix
```

Delete alias:

```
unalias psunix
```